# Video Card does not meet minimum requirements for domain user only

Tags: windows-xp, video, permissions

I have 2 different domain users that are attempting to open an in-house developed application when they are told that their video card does not meet the minimum requirements to run the app.

If I right-click and press 'Run as..' and use either my domain login, local admin or domain admin account it works fine! Not sure what is going on here!

This is happening on 2 (identical) machines with 2 different domain logins. Both are:

- Dell Optiplex 780
- nVidia GT240 1GB Video
- 3GB Ram
- latest drivers - 260.99
- 1 x 24" LCD running 1920x1200, 32bit colors @ 60Hz
- 1 x 17" LCD running 1280x1024, 32bit colors @ 60Hz
- Hardware acceleration is enabled
- Direct X 9.0c
- No differences in policies between working and non-working users

I understand that you will not be able to help me if this is an issue with the application, however I feel as though it is more of a user permissions problem.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: This is a stopgap measure but maybe you can add the affected users to the workstation's local administrator group until you figure out a solution or get your app fixed.  Long shot, but have you tried updating the video drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug that was introduced in some of the later nVidia drivers. I switched the primary monitors around and the problem went away. Yes strange, but it works so I'm happy!

Answer (score 0):

Some more info about the two problematic users would have been useful, such as are both XP and which service pack, and what are their video cards and drivers, monitors and display settings (resolution and colors and whether hardware acceleration is enabled), and which DirectX version is installed. A comparison of all these parameters with a computer on which everything works fine would also be useful, also including logins. And last: When you say "user" do you mean "computer" or "login"?

Please update your post with that information.

Without that information, the only advice possible is to ensure that you have the latest video drivers as downloaded from the manufacturer's website.

To find out what the application is doing that requires special permissions, you might use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Not enough. Missing: Monitors, display settings (resolution, colors, hardware acceleration), DirectX version. Is there any difference between computers that work and work-not. And concerning logins : are there policy differences between the works and works-not users.

Comment: Added link to Process Monitor. I am starting to think that the error message may be erroneous and whatever the application is not succeeding in doing may only pertain indirectly to the video.

Comment: More info added. Will give the process monitor a go today and get back to you. cheers

Comment: More questions: Does disabling hardware acceleration change anything? And does dropping the 17" LCD? Are working PCs identical as regarding hardware?

Comment: @harrymc: I just tried disabling the second 17" monitor, and the application WORKED! I re-enabled it and it stopped working! So I then went into the nVidia control panel and switched the primary monitors, and it worked. Could this be a bug in the latest nVdida driver 260.99? It only started happening on SOME machines (a while) after I rolled this driver. Cheers

Comment: Everything is possible. My suggestion was based on the suspicion that the application picks up the 17" as its monitor and refuses to work in 1280x1024. Most probably it badly handles some change in the data returned by the new video driver. Or that the application only behaved correctly because of a bug that was fixed by the latest driver. The appl+new driver may be incompatible on some setups. I wonder if you can debug the appl.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving them full access to the folder that the application is in.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. See the comment on harrymc's answer. Appears to be driver related.

Answer (score 0):

Use Process Monitor and watch for denied reads/writes. Then run it as you and see which ones don't fail.

> I have 2 different domain users that are attempting to open an in-house developed application when they are told that their video card does not meet the minimum requirements to run the app.

Push it back to the guys who developed it - how is this your problem? Other applications work fine with graphical acceleration, I assume.

Comment: downloaded, but did not get to try this as the bandaid solution of switching primary monitors worked first :)  cheers anyways